# Why doesn't git ignore .gitgnore?

Tags: git, gitignore

Why doesn't git ignore .gitignore? Is this a bug or is this a feature? I can't see any reason why one would like to share ones .gitignore file. It feels a bit ironic to have to add .gitignore to .gitignore.

Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Where would be be store all the information about the files/directory to be ignored?

Comment: check also: http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Imagine if your coworker `git clone` your project without your `.gitignore` file and they push there modifications ! It would push all the files you don't want with your `.gitignore` and next time you pull you project you will receive all crap they pushed :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short - it's a feature.

`.gitignore` is not meant as a local file for every developer on a project.

You need to ignore files and folders which are not meant to be committed to the repo by anyone.

Examples: build folders, vendor folders (installed via a package manager - e.g. `node_modules`), binary files.

Here is a nice help article from GitHub: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

You could also check out the [github/gitignore](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files) repository for examples.

E.g. Symfony2 `.gitignore` is ignoring logs, cache, uploads, vendor libraries installed via composer and commonly used binaries like `composer.phar`:

```
# Bootstrap
app/bootstrap*

# Symfony directories
vendor/*
*/logs/*
*/cache/*
web/uploads/*
web/bundles/*

# Configuration files
app/config/parameters.ini
app/config/parameters.yml

# Composer
composer.phar
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a feature. For example in Java you want to ignore all `*.class` files. So every user of your repository have to ensure, that no `*.class` files are committed. Therefore this is a usecase where this `.gitignore` should be available to all users of this repository.

Answer (score 1):

It's a feature.

The purpose of .gitignore files is to ensure that certain files not tracked by Git remain untracked. Thus it should be committed into the repository, in order to share the ignore rules with any other users that clone the repository.

You can also create a global .gitignore file, which is a list of rules for ignoring files in every Git repositories on your computer. For example, you might create the file at ~/.gitignore_global and add some rules to it. To add this file to your global Git configuration, run the following command in your terminal:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

For further information you can check [official documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at it from different angle. There would be probably more people asking **Why does git ignore .gitignore?** or **How to add .gitignore to my repository?** and so on. It would be much more problematic to include .gitignore to repo that to exclude it with adding it explicitly to gitignore. It could looks weird in some way, but you have to get over it.

So, that's why **it is not a bug it is a FEATURE**!!!

Answer (score 0):

Put the following contents in a `.gitignore` file and check it out yourself:

```
*
```

Git ignores the `.gitignore` file!

To 'fix' this you have to:

```
*
!.gitignore
```